# Unable to store session in Redis using Java Spring Boot Session Data Redis

Tags: java, spring-boot, session, redis

I think I have problems saving session information in Redis. I've tried to follow the instruction about `spring-session-data-redis`, but I can't find any session information within redis when I start a request. The following is my code and config.

application.properties file:

```
spring.session.store-type=redis
spring.session.redis.flush-mode= on-save
spring.session.redis.namespace= spring:session
spring.redis.host= 10.10.10.10
spring.redis.port=10000
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Application Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${spring.redis.host}")
    private String redisHostName;

    @Value("${spring.redis.port}")
    private int redisPort;

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(
                redisHostName, redisPort);
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
    }
}
```

And my sample Get request controller:

```
// test only
    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping(value = "/test/test")
    public String justTest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("sessionId", "ssssss");

        String value = (String) session.getAttribute("sessionId").toString();
        return value;
    }
```

Am I missing something? The `spring-session-data-redis` is supposed to store session to Redis automatically, but it seems not acting like that. Do I need `spring-session` dependency and `spring-data-redis` dependency? The redis connection is ok, I set it to listen to all interfaces.

It seems I can retrieve the session id when I start a request, but why the session is not inserted into Redis?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I am facing the same issue and I browsing the sample projects from spring boot for a solution

Comment: Hi @billcyz, did your problem get's solved ? I ran into the same situation and looking for answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63326384/setting-spring-session-on-redis-server

Answer (score 1):

`spring.session.redis.flush-mode= IMMEDIATE`

```java
/**
     * Flush mode for the Redis sessions. The default is {@code ON_SAVE} which only
     * updates the backing Redis when {@link SessionRepository#save(Session)} is invoked.
     * In a web environment this happens just before the HTTP response is committed.
     * <p>
     * Setting the value to {@code IMMEDIATE} will ensure that the any updates to the
     * Session are immediately written to the Redis instance.
     * @return the {@link RedisFlushMode} to use
     * @since 1.1
```

[Link to docs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session-data-redis/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/EnableRedisHttpSession.java)

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Comment: spring.session.redis.flush-mode= on-save, will save the data just before the HTTP response is committed.