# Setting spring session on redis server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, redis

I am writing my rest apis using spring boot. And I am trying to maintain user's session on redis server. Redis is up and running on the default port `6379`. I have used the lettuce jar to make connection to the redis server. But seems like my session is not being set on redis server. I try to get the session object set using uuid, and it return something like this

```
127.0.0.1:6379> get 02978830-2f35-47b7-a367-1f48e40d0ea0
(nil)
```

From redis cli, I am able to set and get the key values.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set 123 123dummy
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> get 123
"123dummy"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

This is code snippet where I am trying to see if the user has been logged in depending on their active session, if the session is there then I am returning user. Else I am logging em and then setting session on redis server and then returning user.

```
UserAttributes findUserByEmailIdOrPhoneNumber(HttpServletRequest request,
      @RequestParam(value = "userLoginWay", required = false) String userLoginWay,
      @RequestParam(value = "userPassword", required = false) String userPassword,
      @RequestParam(value = "session", required = false) String session) {
    if(request.getSession().getAttribute(session) != null) {
        //we have session return user
        return user;
    } else {
        login(userLoginWay, userPassword)
        //set the session in redis here
        String sessionUuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        request.getSession().setAttribute(sessionUuid, user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

This user is the object which I am trying to set as a session value and uuid as a key.
This is how I am trying to connect to the redis server

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class SessionConfig extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory();
    }

}
```

This is what I have in `application.properties`

```
#Configuring Redis server to manage sessions
spring.session.store-type=redis
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=6379
```

Any idea what's wrong with this ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the connection with redis server using its default constructor.

```
return new LettuceConnectionFactory(new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(host, port));
```

1. You can get values from properties file using `@value` or better method is marking the redis @configuration class with `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.redis")`
2. add fields String host, int port with respective getters and setters.

Comment: Hi Vivkek, thank you for writing. But I think creating a default constructor also creates a connection. If you look at the lettuce class, it's default value is localhost and port 6379

Comment: Please see the RedisStanaloneConfiguration, it has the default host and port as localhost:6379.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/3022efa843ed713249063194b8f41acbabcb096d/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisStandaloneConfiguration.java#L31

Comment: So, if you want to use default then you don't need to add properties in application.properties file and create session using
```return new LettuceConnectionFactory(new RedisStandaloneConfiguration());```

Comment: Yes, I have removed em. You can also create connection using `return new LettuceConnectionFactory();`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, So I got it on my own, I did some changes in session config class and initialize it by extending `AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer`

```
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class SessionConfig {

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory();
    }
}
```

By extending `AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer`, ensures that Spring Bean by the name of `springSessionRepositoryFilter` is registered with our Servlet Container for every request. For more information refer [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/java-redis.html)

```
public class SessionConfigInitializer extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {

    public SessionConfigInitializer() {
        super(SessionConfig.class);
    }
}
```

After this when I looked in the redis server I can see something like this

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys '*'
1) "spring:session:expirations:1597497540000"
2) "spring:session:index:org.springframework.session.FindByIndexNameSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_INDEX_NAME:admin"
3) "spring:session:sessions:expires:dc2172eb-2282-4600-9cd3-7f5d9bbb62b8"
4) "spring:session:sessions:dc2172eb-2282-4600-9cd3-7f5d9bbb62b8"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

The other aspect is from the redis server, once you set your session, depending upon what the value you are setting you need to retrieve it. Redis support six types `string, list, set, zset, hash and stream`. In my case it was hash so to see the value the command will be `HGETALL <key>`